# Searching a data frame via a range of datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am wondering would I be able to search a data frame base on a column with datetime data, but I want to search for rows where the datetime are within a certain value.

```
  Time                   User
1 2017-07-13 18:30:18 .  Gary
2 2017-07-13 13:30:23 .  Mary
3 2017-07-13 02:30:18 .  Tim
4 2017-07-12 12:11:44 .  Jim
5 2017-07-12 03:31:54 .  Tom
6 2017-07-11 01:21:21 .  John
7 2017-07-11 05:32:12 .  Sam
```

Lets say I want to search for all rows where the date is lands between 7-13-17 00:00:00 to 7-13-17 15:00:00. The result would be:

```
2 2017-07-13 13:30:23 .  Mary
3 2017-07-13 02:30:18 .  Tim
```

Is there a way I could slice the data selection to be that exact? I realize I could technically just create an If/elif statement to basically do this but just wondering if there is an easier method as I would be creating multiple If/elif statements to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#if necessary convert to datetime
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df = df[df['Time'].between('2017-07-13', '2017-07-13 15:00:00')]
print (df)
                 Time  User
2 2017-07-13 13:30:23  Mary
3 2017-07-13 02:30:18   Tim
```

Or [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = df.query("'2017-07-13' < Time < '2017-07-13 15:00:00'")
print (df)
                 Time  User
2 2017-07-13 13:30:23  Mary
3 2017-07-13 02:30:18   Tim
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work. This uses Pandas subsetting and indexing functionalities:

```
df[(df['Time'] >= '2017-07-13 13:30:23') & (df['Time'] <= '2017-07-13 15:00:00')]
```